# Does typescript have syntactic sugar around returning a value or throwing an exception if that value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I find myself wanting to do something like this a lot (pseudocode):

```
const something = somethingElse || throw an error
```

This would throw an error if `somethingElse` were falsy. Here's another example, written in real typescript:

```
const accessToken = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN ?? throw new Error("The environment variable ACCESS_TOKEN was undefined or null");
```

This doesn't compile because the right-hand side needs to be an expression. **Is there a way to write code functionally equivalent to the above while being comparable in terseness?**

I can do the following, but I find it obnoxious to type and it uses up a lot of vertical space:

```
  const accessToken = process.env.PATREON_CREATORS_ACCESS_TOKEN;
  if (accessToken === undefined) {
    throw new Error("The environment variable PATREON_CREATORS_ACCESS_TOKEN was undefined");
  }
```

I could also create some utility function where you pass in something potentially falsy, and if it is falsy, throw an error. But I'm wondering if typescript/javascript provides some clever syntax to pull this off so I don't have to create such a function.

Comment: This topic doesn't come up in JavaScript that often, but you've run up against the difference between a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) and an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#expressions). And here we see the difference in all their glory. :-)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Why doesn't it come up that much in JavaScript?

Comment: No, this doesn't exist.  And TypeScript has pretty much left the business of introducing new syntactic sugar for JS.  When you [request a new feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md) you have to check a box saying the suggestion doesn't introduce "new syntax sugar for JS" among other things.  If you want this to happen it has to start with JS and then TS will implement it once the proposal reaches Stage 3 of the TC39 process.

Comment: Ah, so, [this](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) is currently in Stage 2, so it's not yet in TS.  But that looks like what you want.  Oof, it's been Stage 2 for 3 years now with no obvious advancement.  So this probably won't happen anytime soon.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, do you want to see this as an answer?  Or is there something still outstanding that I've missed?

Comment: @jcalz That's valuable information, but based on that information, I suppose I'm now looking for the next best thing. If I've proposed the best alternatives, then I would accept that as an answer

Comment: @jcalz your latest link probably includes the next best thing wrt `const __throw = err => { throw err; };` If that's as terse as it's going to get, I'd accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't currently exist in TypeScript.  Generally speaking, TypeScript doesn't adopt features that produce JavaScript output from non-JavaScript syntax.  (Well, it doesn't do this *anymore*.  Some older features like [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) and [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) definitely behave this way. But if these features didn't already exist, they would be declined if you suggested them today.)  If you [file a new feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/new?template=Feature_request.md) you are supposed to check a box confirming that the suggestion "isn't a runtime feature (e.g. library functionality, non-ECMAScript syntax with JavaScript output, new syntax sugar for JS, etc.)".  From  now on, if we want to see new runtime features in TypeScript, they should be [proposed to TC39](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/blob/HEAD/CONTRIBUTING.md#new-feature-proposals), and TypeScript will implement it once the proposal reaches Stage 3 of [the TC39 process](https://tc39.es/process-document/).

There is an [existing proposal for "`throw` expressions"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-throw-expressions) which has been sitting at Stage 2 since sometime in 2017, so it doesn't look promising.  There is also a TypeScript GitHub issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#18535](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18535) and is stuck with status "Waiting for TC39".  I guess we won't see this anytime soon.

---

In the `throw` expressions proposal, there is a workaround that implements something like a throwable expression:

```
const __throw = (err: any) => { throw err; };
```

Which you can see in action with your example:

```
process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? "a token" : undefined;

const accessToken = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN ??
    __throw(new Error("The environment variable ACCESS_TOKEN was undefined or null"));    
// maybe  The environment variable ACCESS_TOKEN was undefined or null 

// but if it gets here then the compiler knows accessToken is defined:   
console.log(accessToken.toUpperCase()); // A TOKEN
```

So that's probably the closest you can get for now; you can either write your own custom utility function, or cryogenically preserve yourself until such time as `throw` expressions reach Stage 3 of the TC39 process.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTCWFsAcHsCcBcAEByAAvAnpApgZ2AHbQAm2yAsAFABuAhrIpLNAMZ66IC8iA3otgWoAuXgF9EtDgCVsLOMQA8ueLFAEA5gBpEy1RsQAfRAFcCpAGZrsxAHyJRVKnILLEAfTfwAFswDuXRAAKbFhYEVoCDABKLjs+bz9+UIBue2THSiZWdgA6AWocgEEAYWKAUQBlCrcAFQB5AGkygDkAwIBZWm8c2AjiaHBAmIVEAAYcgFYYgH5EACJaRHhoAGsBOcQRUwsrYnTKJ2gXJFoWNlxcGtWBAKzz3DzBItLK6vqm1unpqkRf908fNBfIECNh-GVQnBAnMal5sPxBKBmARwAIkHRVLQAEYAG3hJXKVVqjRaiF8khMZmwllBxEQcEQBGMOJxcyiUX2VBA9IY4FoGCx8MAvBuAUp3ELD4fkkUdUQR0fRQNi8YgCa9iR8yRTttTdjzGcycYgMs5cNA8TkcdB1IFTvcrmsCDllgBVSA4WDFSTYIYcxDcwriknNDJAA)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your criteria, but it seems easy enough to do with a function:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=11&ssc=117&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgCYFMBuqA2B7GqAnAOgFscAvASyywEMicCBzYVAOwFoBVAZWGRwBjOMADiuOHFoEAnsABitLHBkAoSDPyhFymaAC8oAGZK4qUAB9QABkugOtq9bZ2A5K7tsArjTte2aEaUbKjIANyqqkb+gpCUOC6QBF6Q4HoAPAAqAHwAFKgAHjAECKCZADSgJHBMBqDuAJSlAKIFglheaFmVOirZoADeqqCglEaguQCEhcUNoKkEOADuoCErzQSLBLnVTA0RIwSokF4ELjMEoLRwoK3tnajd2qYy2REAvpFo7dLmgglwSCgYpCVCSUoDUDsdClABKqH+BGQ6UBBGCTEqqPRfgCqCCIWQ-XeEVU-zYgKugkEYLgmRwAGt2HUkik0rkQdTJERoUQAIIAYX5zR4PAA+pkAPIAaWaADlKq5MuBzNDKIs2CR2ED0NJKLQAEZYcwCoUi8XSuWgJbXUD+QLBUKgRirHxYVz7VRAA)

```ts
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy
type Falsy = false | 0 | -0 | 0n | '' | null | undefined;

function truthy <T>(expr: T, msg = ''): Exclude<T, Falsy> {
  if (!expr) throw new Error(msg);
  return expr as Exclude<T, Falsy>;
}

declare const process: { env: Record<string, string | undefined> };

const accessToken = truthy(process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN, 'The environment variable ACCESS_TOKEN was undefined or null');
```

Comment: This looks like my utility function idea. I'm confused by the type information though. Why not just do `function truthy<T>(expr: T, msg: string): T {    if (!expr) {      throw new Error(msg);    }    return expr;  }` ?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Because that's just an [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) with a side effect (of throwing falsy inputs) if you don't exclude falsy types from the input type on return.

Comment: As opposed to yours which is a...?

Comment: @DanielKaplan I'm not sure if it i's a common enough pattern to have a name, but I'd say that it's an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), except that it also returns the input value, but narrowed by the assertion.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is, I don't see the advantage of yours over mine. I suspect it has something to do with type safety, but I don't see what scenarios yours prevents. As far as I can see, both versions take the same inputs and return the same outputs. Is it that my version's return value would still require falsy checks to use it?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Yes, that's correct.